# read content of File

Tags: java, io

I have written a program for reading the contents of a file.

```
import java.io.*;

public class FileLineReader {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
      FileReader reader =
          new FileReader("C:\\Users\\sriram\\Documents\\Java Programs\\" +
                         args[0]);
      BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(reader); 
      String fileContent;
      while ((fileContent = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(fileContent);
      }
    } catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

So basically it reads contents from a particular folder.  If I give input as `FileLineReader.class` which is the .class file of the Java program the program outputs the bytecode but gives me a beep sound.  For all other files it gives the output properly.

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: 1) Please use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks. 2)  Don't ignore exception output.  Change `catch(Exception e) { }` to `catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }`

Comment: @AdamLiss  Now can you fix 'ignoring the output' ..& wipe my chin? ;)

Comment: I only made the code legible -- _never_ make cosmetic and functional changes in the same revision.  @sriram can change the functionality.  Guy's gotta learn somehow....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FileLineReader.class` is most likely a binary (compiled Java) file that happens to contain a byte with a value of 7, which is the ASCII code for the bell character. Many terminals will beep when an ASCII 7 is displayed.

Comment: How do you know this much dude? Awesome reply :).

Comment: @sriram Back in the dark ages, when we wrote code by candlelight and there were no SoundBlasters, the computer's speaker was all we had to alert us when something interesting happened.

Comment: Ran this program in a mac env. Did not hear any sound. My env.

> java version "1.6.0_31" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
> 1.6.0_31-b04-415-11M3635) 
>Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.6-b01-415, mixed mode)
> and Mac OS Lion 10.7.4

Comment: @AdamLiss I remember choosing every possible option in the "sound configuration screen" as a kid until I could hear something :D

Comment: One of my high school projects was a sheet-music editor. I used the Commodore PET graphics characters to draw the staff and the notes, printed the music by individually addressing the pins on the school's dot-matrix printer, and played it by connecting a speaker to one of the output pins on the back of the computer and generating square waves that matched the frequencies of the notes. I got "chords" by alternating really quickly between two notes. That was the closest we had to a "sound configuration screen." :-)

Answer (score -2):

If you are reading binary files they can contain a sequence of bytes that represent a random sound. When you send such a sequence to standard output the OS will play the sound.

Comment: Not your down-voter, but this is not correct.  See the other answer by Adam.